# How can I run an Outlook VBA module in a VBscript?

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, outlook-2010

I've been working on this issue for a couple of hours now. I have a VBA code, and initially I was trying to convert it to a VBscript and just can't seem to do it. 
My VBA code creates a meeting in outlook in a specific calendar (named Test). This code works perfectly. Now I need the code to run when a command button is clicked in an Outlook Form. VBA modules cant be assigned to buttons in Outlook Forms. So what I would like to do is have a VBscript and call this module. 
I've saved the module in a file path (G:\3500 EDMFO\Script). The file is saved as Module3_Working.bas and I'm not sure if the file extension should be something different. I've tried numerous methods that from othe forums with no success. Please advise as to how I can get this macro to work within a VBscript. Thank you.

```
Sub AddContactsFolder()


If CommandButton1 = False Then

Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder =myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Test")
MsgBox myFolder
Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
'Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Items.Add("Test")
With myNewFolder
.Subject = "Time Off"
.Start = "8/23/2017"
.AllDayEvent = True
.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "20"
.Save
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting this VBA to VBS shouldn't be that difficult with an example.
Take a look at http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f128/solved-script-to-delete-outlook-calendar-entries-542865.html
Unlike the url suggests there is an example of how to add appointments (holidays in this case) to a Outlook calendart using plain Vbscript.
I publish the code here in case it vanishes.

You should save your code with the .vbs extension (eg add_calendar_item.vbs) and declare outlook constants in advance. Declaring variables with "as" some type isn't possible in vbscript.
Run the .vbs file in a CMD console using `cscript.exe add_calendar_item.vbs`

To make it easier drop the dictionary and seachAppts part and use only one appointment like in your VBA sample.

Try with this code

```
Const olFolderCalendar = 9
Const olAppointmentItem = 1
Const olOutOfOffice = 3

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objCalendar = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) 
Set objApptItems = objCalendar.Items

objApptItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
objApptItems.Sort "[Start]"

Set objHoliday = objOutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)  
objHoliday.Subject = "Boxing Day"
objHoliday.Start = "December 26, 2017" & " 9:00 AM"
objHoliday.End = "December 26, 2017" & " 10:00 AM"
objHoliday.AllDayEvent = True
objHoliday.ReminderSet = False
objHoliday.BusyStatus = olOutOfOffice
objHoliday.Save
```

For reference here the original code

```
Const olFolderCalendar = 9
Const olAppointmentItem = 1
Const olOutOfOffice = 3

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objCalendar = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) 
Set objApptItems = objCalendar.Items

objApptItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
objApptItems.Sort "[Start]"

'' List Appointments to add
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
objDictionary.Add "November 24, 2010", "Thanksgiving"    
objDictionary.Add "November 25, 2010", "Thanksgiving"    
objDictionary.Add "December 25, 2010", "Christmas Day"
objDictionary.Add "December 26, 2010", "Boxing Day"
objDictionary.Add "November 24, 2011", "Thanksgiving"    
objDictionary.Add "November 25, 2011", "Thanksgiving"    
objDictionary.Add "December 25, 2011", "Christmas Day"
objDictionary.Add "December 26, 2011", "Boxing Day"

colKeys = objDictionary.Keys

For Each strKey in colKeys
  dtmHolidayDate = strKey
  strHolidayName = objDictionary.Item(strKey)
  '' Check if it already is on the Calendar
  Return = SearchAppts(strHolidayName, FormatDateTime(dtmHolidayDate, vbShortDate))
  If Return = False Then 
    Set objHoliday = objOutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)  
    objHoliday.Subject = strHolidayName
    objHoliday.Start = dtmHolidayDate & " 9:00 AM"
    objHoliday.End = dtmHolidayDate & " 10:00 AM"
    objHoliday.AllDayEvent = True
    objHoliday.ReminderSet = False
    objHoliday.BusyStatus = olOutOfOffice
    objHoliday.Save
  End If
Next

'' Search Function
Function SearchAppts(ByVal strName, strDate)
  SearchAppts = False
  Set objAppointment = objApptItems.GetFirst
  While TypeName(objAppointment) <> "Nothing"
    If TypeName(objAppointment) = "AppointmentItem" then
      If StrComp(objAppointment, strName,1) = 0 Then
        If DateDiff("D", objAppointment.Start, strDate) = 0 Then 
          SearchAppts = True
          Exit Function
        End If  
      End If  
    End If
    Set objAppointment = objApptItems.GetNext
  Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for posting all that information. I actually should've mentioned this in my original post but I was able to create a VBscript code that would add meeting to the default calendar. The portion I could not get was to edit that code and get it to add meetings to a specific calendar. I will however replace the code I managed to put together with the one you posted. This one is much cleaner! Any advice for getting it to post to a different calendar though?

Comment: yes, should be something like 'Set objCalendar = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Parent.Folders("otherCalendar")' where otherCalendar would be the name of that other Calendar Folder

Comment: Hmm I gave it a shot and was given the following error: "The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found." I also tried 'Set objCalendar = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Test")' This code ran through but it still added the meeting to the default calendar.

Comment: Set objCalendar = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(test)